# excel, combine multiple columns into one row

Tags: excel

Am new to this so any help would be greatly appreciated. 
I have an excel spread sheet with multiple columns, and I want to combine several columns into one column but maintain the same row. i.e.

```
from:
Name    Address         Phone1          Phone2          Phone3
Joe box 5           123-456-7890    Null            312-778-2564
Sue 3 w 2nd ST.     345-789-3214    156-879-5461    278-444-5687
Mike    box 12          Null            666-879-4518    777-548-9851

To:
name    address     Phone
Joe box 5       123-456-7890
            Null
            312-778-2564
Sue 3 w 2nd ST. 345-789-3214
            156-879-5461
            278-444-5687
Mike    box 12      Null
            666-879-4518
            777-548-9851
```

Comment: Looks like a pivot table to me :D

Answer (score -1):

Say your information is in columns A and B so:

```
A | B
1 | z
2 | y
3 | x
```

To combine A and B in column C you would write the following in cell C1 and copy it down

```
=A1&B1
```

The final result would be

```
A | B | C
1 | z | 1z
2 | y | 2y
3 | x | 3x
```